# Adjacency Matrix in java, Breadth First Search

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, breadth-first-search, adjacency-matrix

The following code performs a breadth first search algorithm using an adjacency list structure. I was curious. If I were to implement this an adjacency matrix, what kinds of edits would I have to do to the code?

I know I would have to create a grid (n by n matrix), but would my data file have to correspond to this grid structure? Or would I just fill an empty grid structure and implement the level design my text file already has?

I feel that implementing this in actual code is what I am mostly confused about, in regards to the code below (which uses a stack). I've never done bfs using a matrix, only adjacency list.

Here it is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MainM {

    private Graph graph;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public MainM(Graph g) {
        graph = g;
    }

    /**
     * 1 - Create a stack to store all the vertices of our path on.
     * 2 - First push the 'end' vertex on our stack.
     * 3 - Now loop from the highest level back to the first level and
     *     a. loop through each level and
     *     b. check each vertex in that level if it's connected to the
     *        vertex on the top of our stack, if we find a match, push that
     *        match on the stack and break out of the loop.
     * 4 - Now we only need to reverse the collection (stack) before returning 
     *     the path in the "correct" order (from start to finish).
     * 
     * Here's an example ASCII drawing of backtracking from the end vertex "n" 
     * to the starting vertex "g". The arrows, <-, denote the path that was 
     * found.
     * 
     * level:  0      1      2      3       4      5      6    7     8
     *        ---------------------------------------------------------
     *         g <-+  IV     e      I       a   +- III <- o <- VI <- n 
     *             +- V <-+  f   +- II <-+  b   |         p
     *                    +- c <-+       |  d   |
     *                       j           +- h <-+
     *                                      q
     *                                      r
     */
    private List<String> backTrack(List<List<String>> container, String end) {
        Stack<String> path = new Stack<String>();                     // 1
        path.push(end);                                               // 2
        for(int i = container.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {                // 3
            List<String> level = container.get(i);
            String last = path.peek();
            for(String s : level) {                                   // a
                if(graph.isConnectedTo(last, s)) {                     // b
                    path.push(s);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Collections.reverse(path);                                    // 4
        return path;
    }

    /**
     * 1 - Get the level from the 'container' which was added last.
     * 2 - Create a new level to store (possible) unexplored verices in.
     * 3 - Loop through each of the vertices from the last added level, and
     *     a. get the neighboring vertices connected to each vertex,
     *     b. loop through each connecting vertex and if the connecting vertex
     *        has not yet been visited,
     *     c. only then add it to the newly created level-list and mark it as 
     *        visited in our set.
     * 4 - We don't need to search any further if we stumble upon the 'end' 
     *     vertex. In that case, just "return" from this method.
     * 5 - Only make the recursive call if we have found vertices which have 
     *     not been explored yet.
     */
    private void bfs(List<List<String>> container, 
            String end, Set<String> visited) {

        List<String> lastLevel = container.get(container.size()-1);   // 1
        List<String> newLevel = new ArrayList<String>();              // 2

        for(String vertex : lastLevel) {                              // 3
            List<String> edges = graph.getEdges(vertex);              // a
            for(String edge : edges) {                                // b
                if(!visited.contains(edge)) {                         // c
                    visited.add(edge);
                    newLevel.add(edge);
                }
                if(edge.equals(end)) return;                          // 4
            }
        }  
        if(newLevel.size() > 0) {                                     // 5
            container.add(newLevel);
            bfs(container, end, visited);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 1 - Create an empty 'container' to store all the levels from the 
     *     'start'-vertex in. A level is also a list with one or more vertices.
     * 2 - The first level only holds the 'start' vertex, which is added first,
     *     this is the 'init' list.
     * 3 - The 'start' vertex is also stored in a Set which keeps track of all 
     *     the vertices we have encountered so that we don't traverse vertices
     *     twice (or more).
     * 4 - Once we initialized the steps 1-3, we can call the actual BFS-
     *     algorithm.
     * 5 - Once the BFS-algorithm is done, we call the backTrack(...) method 
     *     to find the shortest path between 'end' and 'start' between the 
     *     explored levels of the graph. 
     */
    public List<String> getShortestPath(String start, String end) {
        List<List<String>> container = new ArrayList<List<String>>(); // 1
        List<String> init = new ArrayList<String>();                  // 2
        init.add(start);
        container.add(init);
        Set<String> visited = new HashSet<String>();                  // 3
        visited.add(start);
        bfs(container, end, visited);                                 // 4
        return backTrack(container, end);                             // 5
    }

    /**
     * Main method:
     *  1 - Create a Graph.
     *  2 - Get a shortest path between two vertices.
     *  3 - Print the shortest path.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Graph graph = new Graph("data.txt");                          // 1
        MainM bfsAlgorithm = new MainM(graph);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter starting city: ");
        String shortPath = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter ending city: ");
        String shortPath2 = sc.nextLine();
        List<String> shortestPath = bfsAlgorithm.getShortestPath(shortPath, shortPath2);
        //List<String> shortestPath = 
          //  bfsAlgorithm.getShortestPath("g", "n");                   // 2
        for(int i = 0; i < shortestPath.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(shortestPath.get(i));                    // 3
            System.out.print(i < shortestPath.size()-1 ? " --> " : " ");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the graph class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Graph {

    private Map<String, List<String>> adjacencyList;

    /**
     * Instatiates the 'adjacencyList' and then parse the data file.
     */
    public Graph(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        adjacencyList = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        parseDataFile(fileName);
    }

    /**
     * This is an undirected graph, so we connect 'vertexA' to 'vertexB' 
     * and the other way around.
     */
    public void addConnection(String vertexA, String vertexB) {
        connect(vertexA, vertexB);
        connect(vertexB, vertexA);
    }

    /**
     * A private helper-method to connect 'vertexA' to 'vertexB'.
     * If 'vertexA' alreay exists in our 'adjacencyList', get it's 
     * edges-list and add 'vertexB' to it. If it doesn't exist,  
     * create a new ArrayList, add 'vertexB' to it and put it all 
     * in our 'adjacencyList'.
     */
    private void connect(String vertexA, String vertexB) {
        List<String> edges;
        if(adjacencyList.containsKey(vertexA)) {
            edges = adjacencyList.get(vertexA);
            edges.add(vertexB);
        } else {
            edges = new ArrayList<String>();
            edges.add(vertexB);
            this.adjacencyList.put(vertexA, edges);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns true iff 'vertexA' poits to to 'vertexB'.
     * Note that since this is an undirected graph, we do not 
     * need to check the other way around, the case if 'vertexB' 
     * is points to 'vertexA'.
     */
    public boolean isConnectedTo(String vertexA, String vertexB) {
        List<String> edges = getEdges(vertexA);
        return edges.contains(vertexB);
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the edges of a certain vertex, or throws an 
     * exception if the vertex doesn't exist in this graph.
     */
    public List<String> getEdges(String vertex) {
        List<String> edges = adjacencyList.get(vertex);
        if(edges == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(vertex+" not present in the graph.");
        }
        return edges;
    }

    /**
     * Reads a text file with the graph-data. The text file contains 
     * N-blocks of lines where each block starts with the city followed
     * by N-lines of text representing the city2s and ending with an 
     * empty line.
     */
    private void parseDataFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        while(file.hasNextLine()) {
            String city = file.nextLine().trim();
            while(file.hasNextLine()) {
                String city2 = file.nextLine().trim();
                if(city2.length() == 0) break;
                addConnection(city, city2);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * A Sting representation if this Graph.
     */
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<String> vertices = adjacencyList.keySet().iterator();
        while(vertices.hasNext()) {
            String vertex = vertices.next();
            List<String> edges = adjacencyList.get(vertex);
            builder.append(vertex);
            builder.append(" --> ");
            builder.append(edges);
            builder.append('\n');
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    /**
     * main
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Graph graph = new Graph("data.txt");
            System.out.println(graph);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

here is a text test file:

```
Seattle
  a
  b
  01
  d
  e

II
  c
  h
  q
  r

III
  h
  o
  p

IV
  e
  f
  g

V
  c
  g
  j

VI
  k
  m
  n
  o
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the fun part of OO programming :-)

If you create a common interface for a `Graph` and give 2 implementations (e.g., `AdjListGraph` and `AdjMxGraph`), you don't have to change anything in your `MainM` class except the declaration. Just implement the common functions (`addConnection()`, `isConnectedTo()`, etc.) in the new adjacency matrix based implementation.

I wouldn't consider changing my input data structure. Btw, there are plenty of options to use, the most common is the [Pajek format](https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/pajek-net-format/) -- which may be kinda strange for the first sight.

Also, there are dozens of graphing libs out there ([GraphStream](http://graphstream-project.org), [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net), etc.), take a look on them. You can learn quite a lot by simply browsing those codebases.

Hope that helps something ;]